# Attr: Deserialize deeply nested json?

Tags: python-attrs

I have a deeply nested JSON structure like this:

```
  json_data =  """{
      "title: "...",
      "links": [
        {
          "href": "string",
          "method": {
            "method": "string"
          },
          "rel": "string"
        }
      ]
    }"""
```

my classes:

```
import attr
import typing as ty
import enum
    class HttpMethod(enum.Enum):
        GET = 0
        HEAD = 1
        POST = 2
        PUT = 3
        DELETE = 4
        CONNECT = 5
        OPTIONS = 6
        TRACE = 7
        PATCH = 8


@attr.s(frozen=True, auto_attribs=True)
class LinkInfo:
    href: str = attr.ib()
    link: str = attr.ib(converter=ensure_cls)
    method: HttpMethod = attr.ib(converter=lambda x: x.name)

@attr.s(frozen=True, auto_attribs=True)
class AnalysisTemplateGetModel:
    title: x: str = attr.ib()
    links: ty.List[mlinks.LinkInfo]= attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(list))
```

and I want to deserialize them to attr classes,

```
js = json.loads(**json_data)
```

but the links field of js is still a dictionary, not a LinkInfo object?

```
str(js)
AnalysisTemplateGetModel(..., links=[{'href': 'string', 'method': {'method': 'string'}, 'rel': 'string'}])
```

Comment: Couple of things `js = AnalysisTemplateGetModel(**json.loads(json_data))` I presume and `title :x str =` looks just faulty to me. Then you need a converter for the links to convert them to List of LinkInfo objects